# Angular 2 dynamic dropdown using ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I have response like this

```
Array(3)
        0:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id:1
        is_optional:false
        is_text:false


        1:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id: 2
        is_optional:false
        is_text:false


        2:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id :3
        is_optional: false
        is_text: false
```

html

```
  <div *ngFor="let question of response" class="row">
        <select id="{{option?.id}}" class="dropdown" [(ngModel)]="questions"  (change)= "GetDataselected($event.target.value)">
                          <option *ngFor = "let option of responseoption">{{option?.name_eng}} </option>
                          </select>  
    </div>
```

from above code, i am doing ngFor with response and creating a three dropdowns(resposne), if i select any one dropdown option, all other dropdown are also selecting with same value.how to rid of this.

Please help me.

Comment: All of your dropdowns have the same `ngModel`, therefore their value will be the same if you select an option in any of them. I don't know what you're binding to but make sure that all the select fields have a unique `ngModel`

Comment: Thank you, it is dynamic dropdowns, dropdown are created based on response array.

Comment: Is this a typo: `[(ngModel)]="questions"`? Should it be `[(ngModel)]="question"`?